# iPhone camera, how to avoid cameraOverlay on preivew view; How to know when entering preview view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

On the camera workflow, the photo is captured and on the next screen, let's call it *choose-screen*, you can choose if you want to use this photo or retake it.

**How do I know, when the camera enteres the *preview view*?**

My issue is that I have added a button to access the camera roll, which works fine. The obstacle is, when taking a photo and entering the *preview view* (2. Camera View), the button hides the "use photo" option. So I cannot select it. I want to hide the button when entering the *preview view* or just avoid the *preview view*.

[image]

Below my code

#### CamViewScreen.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface CamViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *lastTakenImage;
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender;
@end
```

#### CamViewScreen.m

```c
#import "CamViewController.h"

@interface CamViewController ()

@end

@implementation CamViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

int isAction = 0; // Photo, 1: CameraRoll, 2: Cancel

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }
    isAction = 0;
    [self cameraRoll];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // isAction = 0 Photo, 1: CameraRoll, 2: Cancel
    DLog(@"###### isAction> %d", isAction);

    switch (isAction) {
        case 1:
            [self selectPhoto:nil];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            break;
        default:
            [self takePhoto:nil];
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraOverlayView = [self addCameraRollButton];  // suggestion from omz

    // [self addCameraRollButton:picker.view];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)prepareCameraRoll {
    isAction = 1;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.image = chosenImage;

    isAction = 0;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCameraView" sender:info];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    isAction = 2; // Cancel
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


}
# pragma mark - for the cameraOverlayView // suggestion from omz
- (UIView *)addCameraRollButton {
    float startY = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0) ? 500.0 : 410.0;

    UIButton *rollButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rollButton.frame = CGRectMake(230.0, startY, 60.0, 60.0);
    rollButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [rollButton setImage:self.lastTakenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rollButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    [rollButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prepareCameraRoll) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return rollButton;
}

# pragma mark - CameraRoll function and presentation
- (void)addCameraRollButton:(UIView *)picker {
    float startY = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0) ? 500.0 : 410.0;

    UIButton *rollButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rollButton.frame = CGRectMake(230.0, startY, 60.0, 60.0);
    rollButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [rollButton setImage:self.lastTakenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rollButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    [rollButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prepareCameraRoll) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [picker addSubview:rollButton];
}

-(void)cameraRoll {
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                                 usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                     if (nil != group) {
                                         // be sure to filter the group so you only get photos
                                         [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

                                         [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                                             if (asset) {
                                                 ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                                                 //  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage]];
                                                 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullScreenImage]];
                                                 [self setLastTakenImage:img];
                                                 *stop = YES;
                                             }
                                         }];
                                     }


                                     *stop = NO;
                                 } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                 }];
}


#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    CameraViewController *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    cvc.image = self.image;
    DLog(@"%@, cvcimage", cvc.image);
}
@end
```

Comment: Use the `cameraOverlayView` property of `UIImagePickerController` to add your custom button.

Comment: @omz did it, but does not solve the problem. Still the added button is over the "use photo" button. Updated my post, how I did it with the `cameraOverlayView` property.

Comment: Is your CameraViewController (which based on your header file is different from the CamViewController) being called when the photo is taken?  You call the method `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCameraView" sender:info]` from the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method, which is called when you take the picture.  So "toCameraView" is where you need to implement your 'use photo' button.

Comment: @omz `CameraViewController` is first called, after the photo was taken; strictly spoken when the button "use photo" is pressed, then the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is called. The camera and function to take a picture is only available on `CamViewController`. The "use photo" button is the default one, which comes with the `UIImagePickerController`. I wonder why the overlay is available on two modal view (the camera where you take the picture, and the preview where you use/retake the photo). How do folks have different overlays here...

Comment: @jeremyw see comment above.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found a solution. Was hard to find, but finally got it. The solution is described at [UIImagePicker cameraOverlayView appears on Retake screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17973384/1933185). Additionally I add my working code for others who have the same problem.

The use of the `NSNotificationCenter` with **@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"** and **@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"** is the key!

#### CamViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface CamViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *lastTakenImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *picker;
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender;
@end
```

#### CamViewController.h

```c
#import "CamViewController.h"

@interface CamViewController ()

@end

@implementation CamViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

int isAction = 0; // Photo, 1: CameraRoll, 2: Cancel

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil ];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem" object:nil ];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }
    isAction = 0;
    [self cameraRoll];
}

-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)message {
    if ([[message name] isEqualToString:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"]) {
        // Remove overlay, so that it is not available on the preview view;
        self.picker.cameraOverlayView = nil;
    }
    if ([[message name] isEqualToString:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"]) {
        // Retake button pressed on preview. Add overlay, so that is available on the camera again
        self.picker.cameraOverlayView = [self addCameraRollButton];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // isAction = 0: Photo, 1: CameraRoll, 2: Cancel
    DLog(@"###### isAction> %d", isAction);

    switch (isAction) {
        case 1:
            [self selectPhoto:nil];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            break;
        default:
            [self takePhoto:nil];
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.allowsEditing = YES; // if this is NO or missing, the image the image will not be in info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraOverlayView = [self addCameraRollButton];

    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)prepareCameraRoll {
    isAction = 1;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {

    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; 

    isAction = 0;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCameraView" sender:info];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    isAction = 2; // Cancel
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

# pragma mark - CameraRoll function and presentation
- (UIView *)addCameraRollButton {
    float startY = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0) ? 500.0 : 410.0;

    UIButton *rollButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rollButton.frame = CGRectMake(230.0, startY, 60.0, 60.0);
    rollButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [rollButton setImage:self.lastTakenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rollButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    [rollButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prepareCameraRoll) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return rollButton;
}

-(void)cameraRoll {
    // have to import assetlibrary framework!!!
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                                 usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                     if (nil != group) {
                                         // be sure to filter the group so you only get photos
                                         [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

                                         [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                                             if (asset) {
                                                 ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                                                 //  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage]];
                                                 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullScreenImage]];
                                                 [self setLastTakenImage:img];
                                                 *stop = YES;
                                             }
                                         }];
                                     }


                                     *stop = NO;
                                 } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                 }];
}


#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    CameraViewController *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    cvc.image = self.image;
    DLog(@"%@, cvcimage", cvc.image);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: @matt glad to hear that it could help you :)

Comment: @jerik, is using these two notification considered as the private APIs? Just curious, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @jing i just found the solution in the stackoverflow thread referenzed in the answer. It was really hard to find. If there is a documentation its hidden good ;)

Comment: @jerik have you submitted your app to iTunes that uses these notifications? does apple approved your app?

Comment: @Bhushan Yes I submitted it to the apple app store. There were no issues in the approval process regarding these notifications.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Swift. I am having trouble converting the ObjC (using my knowledge of it at least) to Swift. @matt, any help?

Answer (score 2):

In swift 4 for future references. I'm using **isHidden** because I had problems to show it back when the user select Retake.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"),
                                               object: nil,
                                               queue: nil)
        {
            _ in

            overlayView.isHidden = true
            overlayView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"),
                                               object: nil,
                                               queue: nil)
        {
            _ in
            overlayView.isHidden = false
            overlayView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
```

Comment: This is clean and worked great for Swift 5/XCode 12.3.  Should have more upvotes here in 2021.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just posting here for future Swift references, if anyone needs it.

I've been having the same issue, and after a day of research, with a lot of trail and error, I found a way that removes the cameraOverlayView from the image preview.

When you take a photo the "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" triggers. Luckily we can utilize this by creating an observer with a closure. Inside the closure we can set the cameraOverlayView to nil, and thereby removing your custom view before entering preview.

This works in Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62), with Swift 3.

I have added the code snippet for you to utilize if needed.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"), object:nil, queue:nil, using: { note in
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = nil
)}
```

Comment: You're my hero!  Thanks!

Comment: @bluefox I'm happy that the solution worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

@jerik-I saw you amended your question.  You can set the UIImagePickerController property `showsCameraControls` to no, which will eliminate the preview screen- this hides the default controls as well (and lets you take multiple pictures without dismissing the camera), but since you are using `cameraOverlayView`, it's immaterial. This only works if the media type is camera, and you will have to implement the `takePicture` function of the UIImagePickerDelegate protocol to take the picture programatically.

I haven't tried the hack of changing the controls of the preview screen.  If you really want to keep the preview screen, you need to add logic to your own `takePhoto` function that determines if you should call `picker.cameraOverlayView = [self addCameraRollButton]` (taking a picture) or not (the preview screen), but I'm not sure if you can change the cameraOverlayView for the preview screen dynamically - it seems like something Apple wouldn't want you messing with.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: It's tricky, basically I want to use the default buttons of the camera, but this means to have the preview (as you mentioned). Looks like I have to go the road and create an complete overlay, as well with the default buttons. But I do not know where I can get the default buttons, like cancel, flash, and twist camera.